# SQL Server connection to a local database is failing all of a sudden. Nothing in code changed

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have been using an SQL Server Express database residing on my local computer with a couple of applications in C#. One of them has always worked without any problems. I used the same connection string to the same database in the same location for another application, but every time I run the app, the first time it tries to process an SQL connection, I get an error. I stop debugging and start it again and it always connects without a problem the second time. This had been working this way for a couple of months. Tonight it stopped working at all. Now every time I run the program it will not connect. Nothing has changed. I did not touch the connection string or any of the code involved with it. It makes no sense! I went to the older program which uses the same connection, the one that always worked every time, and it will not connect and I get the same error.

The relevant code is:

```
conString="Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\"Path
name"\\Employees.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"; 

SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(conString);
sqlConn.Open();
```

I get the error when it tries to open this connection. The error message is:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: Check if your SQL Browser service is running. You also shouldn't need the `AttachDbFilename` parameter - just leave the database attached. Have you changed your Windows login at all in the last day or so?

Comment: If I substitute "AttachDbFilename" with "Database" it does not work. What parameter should replace "AttachDbFilename"???

Comment: There can be several reasons for what you are seeing, and any further comment would be pure speculation without seeing what you've got.

Answer (score 2):

If you're 100% sure that your connection string is correct, then this is not a C# issue, or a problem with code in any way. The SQL drivers in the .NET framework use the SQL Browser service to resolve some connection strings, so it's likely that this is not running.

As far as I'm aware, if you specify a TCP-based connection string (with a DNS-resolvable hostname or and IP address, and a port number), then the SQL Browser is not required. However, if you specify a DataSource value of [hostname]/[instance-name] (e.g. .\SQLEXPRESS), then the Browser Service will be called.

The .NET SQL driver sends a request over UDP (port 1434) to the SQL Browser Service, attempting to resolve the requested instance name. The browser service responds with an enumeration of all the SQL instances on the machine. Of course, if the browser service is not running, you receive an 'Error 26'...

Hope this explains what's going on...

Comment: Thank you for your answers. It is possible, and now that I think about it, even likely that the SQL Browser service had stopped. When I got on the next day everything worked. BUT....it still will not connect the first time and I get the following timeout error when it tries to open the Sqlconnection: "Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding." I stop debugging and then run it again and it always connects from that point on. I closed Visual Studio and opened it again and opened the project and ran it and it timed out again